# Programmatically close app when user exits app?

Tags: ios, xcode, terminate

I have a simple game, made using the storyboard.

Obviously, when the user exits the application, it closes and stays in the background (no forced quit or closed).

Is there anything you can do, either in Xcode project settings or programmatically, that will close the app upon exiting, so when the user clicks the app icon, it runs from the start as normal? Just as if it had been manually closed?

Comment: Despite closing this as a duplicate, I must ask why you want to do this? Why not let the user return to the game where they left off?

Comment: Well, my game runs on the first view controller, and when the user returns to the game, I want the view controller to start from the beginning, no half way through the game... If that makes sense.

Comment: You could simply reset the game when the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: Yeh, that would be great. Is there a good resource/tutorial that shows this?

Comment: Because, I'd need to remove all animations and recall the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, but NO, you shouldn't do that. Apple will reject your application when you submit it, if you try to exit the app programatically. IOS apps should work the way apple recommends it to work.

From their [**official site**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html):

> Warning: Do not call the exit function. Applications calling exit will
>   appear to the user to have crashed, rather than performing a graceful
>   termination and animating back to the Home screen.

**EDIT**

Just for satisfying your curiosity, you can call `exit(0);` to close your app programatically.

Comment: Yes, there is a way that Apple will accept. See the duplicate.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Is there anything you can do to make the application revert to the first view controller and run the controllers viewDidLoad as you'd expect upon reopening the app, even after it has been minimised?

Comment: @rmaddy I misunderstood the question that he was speaking about an exit button. :-)

Comment: @Reanimation You can follow the instruction in the duplicate that rmmady mentioned. It will close your app once it goes to background, except when the lock screen is active with your app in foreground. With that solution, your app will still run behind a lock screen.

Comment: Oh cool. I'll check it out. Thanks guys.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT More correctly, the app never goes to the background. Pressing Home or switching to another app will fully terminate the app.